# Why Spring Security permitAll() is not working with OAuth2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a REST API secured with OAuth2.0
I am able to get the access-token using *http://localhost:8085/auth/token?grant_type=password&username=22@gmail.com&password=mypass*(along with username pass basic auth).
But when I am trying to access *http://localhost:8085/api/v1/signup* , API returns a `401 unauthorized` error.
Though I have used `antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()`, why API is expecting a `access-token` to access this resource? Passing `access-token` along with this request would signup a user.
This is my resource server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

//require beans and methods here

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}

@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    .csrf().disable();
}
}
```

**Update**: As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296869/spring-security-permitall-still-considering-token-passed-in-authorization-header) thread, I ignored `/signup` at ``, but that also didn't worked.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.rest.security" })
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //other Beans & methods

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<RequestMatcher> requestMatchers = new ArrayList<RequestMatcher>();
        requestMatchers.add(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/signup/**"));

        http.
        requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(requestMatchers)).
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup/**")
        .permitAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the issue. It was the context path which was causing the issue. I am having a dispatcher servlet defined with a mapping URL `/api/v1/*` and as one can see my `signup` request, it contains a context path i.e  `http://localhost:8085/api/v1/signup`

For OAuth2 configuration in Spring, we need to take extra care of context path. First, it should be defined in the AuthorizationServer

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) { 
        endpoints
        .prefix("/api/v1") //here
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
  }
```

Then, the context must be added to the `permitAll()` path like this

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/signup").permitAll()  //context path here
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Up till now, the signup request is still expected to pass a access token with it. For removing the OAuth security from signup, we need to remove security at the `WebSecurity`, which can be done using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.rest.security" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/signup");
     }
 //////////// OR use below method ///////////
/*  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup/**").permitAll();
    }
*/
}
```

Note, there is no use to add context path to the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration.

Comment: I had a similar problem without the context. If I was to put in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` a `.antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()` then GET requests worked. But any POST would require a token. It worked when I added under the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` your suggested `configure(WebSecurity webSecurity)` lines. Why is this? Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @idipous I didn't get time to deeply look into what's going on. Once I get, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the order is the issue and matchers **.

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

 http    
   .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/signup**")
     .permitAll()
     .and()
   .authorizeRequests()
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and() .csrf().disable();  

}
```

Comment: Not helpful. Still same `401 unauthorized` error. And btw, `/signup*` is used to match paths like `/signup?xyz&abc=1` and `/signup/**` will match `/signup/user` kind of paths